# Add category image prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to create category in prestashop with a php script. My question is how can i define images ? Is there a function to do that ?

I precise I don't want to use csv import, only php script.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

More information of what exactly you need to do with images? For what?

What you mean define? Asociate with category? Upload?

btw: take a look at: classes/Image.php may be it there.